# Can't install the new TensorFlow distribution

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I've just tried installing the new tensor flow release 1.9 for Raspbian, but with no success. Running pip install tensorflow fails with

```
Downloading/unpacking tensorflow
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement tensorflow
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for tensorflow
Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log
```

The same happens with pip3.

Any ideas? Or am I too quick off the mark in downloading it?

Comment: I installed it a couple of days ago, and it should be available. Do you have a file called /etc/pip.conf? If yes, what's the contents? BTW: check the .log file mentioned above to maybe get more details.